# AWS Sync to S3 [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Syncing to S3 from a Samba server, we have run into the same error on the same file for the past two weeks:

> upload failed: ../data/backup/SERVER/Full/Client
>   Files/A/CLIENT/NCI.MPG to s3://SERVER/Full/Client
>   Files/A/CLIENT/NCI.MPG

This error appears when I tail our log file.

When I run the sync command for that file using the CLI, I the following error is thrown:

> [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/data/backup/SERVER/Full/Client
>   Files/A/DOMAIN.com/NCI.MPG/'

There is another backup running daily that uses directories/files with spaces in the name that seems to be handled just file, however our large weekly sync errors. Below is the sync command we are calling in a bash script on a daily basis:

```
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync "/data/backup/$DIR" "s3://INTERNAL-SERVER/Full" --delete 2>&1 | tee -a $FILE ;;
```

`$DIR` is defined previously as an array containing all folders within `/data/backup/SERVER/Full/`. We step through each folder within `$DIR` and up until the error is thrown, three hours into the upload, everything works fine.

I had the idea to just use the --recursive switch in place of the directory array but it doesn't make sense to me why the command would work properly six days out of the week and then on the day we run our full upload, it seems to randomly error on that one specific file, two weeks in a row.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix this problem with the clever use of a call that was listed in an ancient version of the CLI, that one AWS support member didn't know existed and another said no longer worked:

```
--content-type "UTF-8"
```

This has actually cleared up a number of our issues but leaves us having to call our "Full" backup cron job manually as for some reason the cron job errors out when called automatically.